# why is waiting until the page is loaded to execute this code important

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Why is waiting until the page is loaded to execute this code important ?

window.onload = function () {

//javascript code

}

Comment: Are you asking "why you would run code after the page has loaded?"... or is the use of "important" an attempt to make us jump to attention and answer you as quickly as possible?

Comment: no im asking why it is important to use window.onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Javascript functions are intended to modify the content or structure of the DOM, but trying to affect the document programmatically should not be undertaken until the document is fully loaded. The onload event fires *after* the target document is loaded, thus ensuring that the code attached to the event is capable of affecting the corresponding document.

Comment: Exactly! If you do not ensure that the docuemnt has loaded before attempting to manipulate objects in the page, you may produce a JavaScript error.

Answer (score 0):

It is important, but you can also not use it.

You need to wait for the page to load when scripts need to modify/read elements in the page (they need to exist, and while the page is loading they don't exist yet): if you don't interact with the page, you don't need to use window.onload.

Answer (score 0):

window.onload will execute the code once everything is loaded. This comes into importance when you need any element in the page to be present in the page for the script to execute.

eg: You are trying to alert a value in a textbox which has a default value and we have a script to alert this. Now this script should be executed once all the elements have been loaded. putting this code within the window.onload will ensure that it is loaded before execution.

on the other side if you do  not need anything to be loaded for the script to run it need not be in the window.load.